# Next.JS router.query returns undefined for arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to pass objects of an array in another page using `router.query`, single objects such as `router.query.title` work fine, but when it comes to arrays such as `router.query.reviews` it returns something like this `reviews: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']`. I've tried using `router.isReady` but nothing seems to change

**Example object in the array**

```
 {
    title: "Center-Hall",
    reviews: [
      {
        title: "Wislong Chew",
        comment: "jsdncjnsd csdncjds csjcnsdj csjdcn cdc djndc",
      },
      {
        title: "Wisdsdlong Chew",
        comment: "jsdncjnsd csdncjds csjcnsdj csjdcn cdc djndc",
      },
    ],
  },
```

**Parent**

```
{array.map((item) => (
          <Grid key={item} item>
            <Card
              label={item.title}
              onClick={() =>
                router.push({
                  pathname: "/page",
                  query: {
                    title: item.title,
                    reviews: item.reviews,
                  },
                })
              }
            />
          </Grid>
        ))}
```

**Next Page**

```
function index() {
  const router = useRouter();


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!router.isReady) return;
    console.log(router.query);
  }, [router.isReady]);


  const Reviews = () =>
      <ReviewCard
        reviewsList={router.query.reviews}
      />
    );

  return (
      <Box>
          <Typography>{router.query.title}</Typography>
          <Reviews />
      </Box>
  );
}

export default index;
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the `reviews` array data that you are trying to pass in the queryString? I suspect that they may be non-serializable values.

Comment: @DrewReese I've updated the question, you can now see an example of an item of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you passing an array using router.query to another page parse it into a json string using the JSON.stringify method and on the next page parse the string into an array using the JSON.parse method

## Parent

```js
{array.map((item) => (
          <Grid key={item} item>
            <Card
              label={item.title}
              onClick={() =>
                router.push({
                  pathname: "/page",
                  query: {
                    title: item.title,
                    reviews: JSON.stringify(item.reviews),
                  },
                })
              }
            />
          </Grid>
        ))}
```

## Next Page

```js
function index() {
  const router = useRouter();


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!router.isReady) return;
    console.log(router.query);
    console.log(JSON.parse(router.query.reviews))
  }, [router.isReady]);


  const Reviews = () =>
      <ReviewCard
        reviewsList={JSON.parse(router.query.reviews)}
      />
    );

  return (
      <Box>
          <Typography>{router.query.title}</Typography>
          <Reviews />
      </Box>
  );
}

export default index;
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens when the array item is a JSON object.You can pass array but not array of objects.

```
 router.push({
                  pathname: "/planterupdate",
                  query: {
                    title: "test",
                    textArray: ["1","2","3","4"],//will work
                    reviews: [{num:1},{num:2},{num:3},{num:4}],//will not work
                    numArray: [5,6,7,8],//will work
                  },
                })
```

Sample log of query
{title: 'test', textArray: Array(4), reviews: Array(4), numArray: Array(4)}
numArray: (4) ['5', '6', '7', '8']
reviews: (4) ['', '', '', '']
textArray: (4) ['1', '2', '3', '4']
title: "test"